# Is there a way to get the path of a photo using the Flickr api?

Tags: flickr

When I upload a photo using the Flickr API it returns the photo id. I can then use that to find out what server the photo is on but i also need to know what farm that server is on.

Is there a way to get the farm id or some easier way to get the full path to an uploaded photo using the API, with C#.

Example:

http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4086/5198724006_3cb5f9b00c_m.jpg

Where farm5 is the farm, and 4086 is the server id in that farm.

Thanks, Scott.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `flickr.photos.getInfo` API method, which includes all of the information you need to build the URL of the photo.

Answer (score 0):

here what you are looking http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html
example response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <sizes canblog="0" canprint="0" candownload="1">
    <size label="Square" width="75" height="75" source="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3268/2911094162_6701747b52_s.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwink/2911094162/sizes/sq/" media="photo" />
    <size label="Large Square" width="150" height="150" source="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3268/2911094162_6701747b52_q.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwink/2911094162/sizes/q/" media="photo" />
    <size label="Thumbnail" width="100" height="99" source="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3268/2911094162_6701747b52_t.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwink/2911094162/sizes/t/" media="photo" />
    <size label="Small" width="198" height="197" source="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3268/2911094162_6701747b52_m.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwink/2911094162/sizes/s/" media="photo" />
    <size label="Original" width="198" height="197" source="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3268/2911094162_f191d3aea2_o.jpg" url="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ewwink/2911094162/sizes/o/" media="photo" />
  </sizes>
</rsp>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out one way to get the direct url to an uploaded image.

First you need to upload the image

```
strPhotoId = flickr.UploadPicture(strPath);
```

Then you need to create a photoset adding that image to it.

```
flickr.PhotosetsCreate("1","HI",strPhotoId);
```

Then you search for that photoset and grab the url from it.

```
pscCollection = flickr.PhotosetsGetList();

//grabs the photo path from the collection
foreach (Photoset item in pscCollection)
{
   strPhotoPath = item.PhotosetSmallUrl;
}
```

Where strPhotoPath is the direct path to the photo.

Hope this helps anyone in need.

Scott